# What do I do if things don't run properly using Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I'm trying to use [Anaconda](http://anaconda.com) to run some Python software, but I just get an error message when I try to start Jupyter, Spyder, or R Studio.  Something like the following:

[image]

The error text is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 148, in 
from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/bin/spyder", line 6, in 
sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in 
requirements.check_qt()
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
import qtpy
File "/Users/ijstokes/anaconda/envs/spyder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 154, in 
raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you posting a question and an answer? Just to be clear there are already answers for this exact question and documentation on anacondas website with this info as well.

Comment: Because StackOverflow encourages it.  Write a question and you'll see that you're given the option to answer your own question.  And they also document this feature here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: That would assume that this information is not already documented or an existing Q/A. This is not the case and that makes your Q/A just repeated information.

Comment: Though I think a better way to ask this question is to post the actual error message rather than just a screenshot. This way the error is searchable where the image not as much. Specify what you are trying to solve. Yes the screenshot can be helpful to show when you might get this error overall the most helpful information is what specific error you are getting.

Comment: Regarding the Anaconda website documentation: I work on Anaconda, and like many engineers we find that users are more likely to look for answers on StackOverflow than in our documentation which doesn't really address these kinds of questions.  Yes, there are FAQ and Troubleshooting sections, but these are focused on Anaconda itself, not, for the most part, on the packages that are inside Anaconda.  And to some degree I think you could make exactly that same argument for 50% of the questions and answers on StackOverflow.  If people just said "RTFM" then SO wouldn't be so amazing.

Comment: @scrappedcola good point, I'll add in that error text.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech You're welcome to point to a URL where this question is already answered.  Like I said: I'm an engineering developing Anaconda and I'm not aware of an answer to it anywhere in the official documentation.

Comment: @IanSR Well I know I have found tutorials in the past for this same issues as I have used Anaconda in the past with the same issue. However I cannot find the link. I do know that it was all command line based to fix the issues so it was not being fixed within the Anaconda GUI. Simply googling [anaconda ModuleNotFoundError: No module named](https://www.google.com/search?q=anaconda+ModuleNotFoundError+No+module+named&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) will return several Github links to many similar issues with answers on how to correct the problem.

Comment: I thought my fix for this was just to install the pyqt binary or is that a different error?

Comment: @roganjosh in this particular case that would be the fix to the problem.  I was trying to document a general class of problems and provide a general solution strategy.

Answer (score 6):

This can be frustrating and there are a few steps you can take to try and resolve it.  Usually it is because of a broken software version, and less frequently due to conflicting software or libraries on your system.

### Update the package (GUI)

Try to update Spyder (or Jupyter) in Navigator.  See this screenshot:

[image: Package update using Navigator]

1. Select *"Environments"*
2. Search for *"Spyder"*
3. If an update is possible it will show a blue arrow. Click on this.  If you have the latest version it will be a green checkbox.
4. This green checkbox will turn into a blue arrow
5. Click on the *"Apply"* button at the bottom right
6. Try again!

### Create a test environment

If that doesn't resolve the problem try creating a minimal test environment:

[image]

1. Select *"Environments"*
2. Click on *"+ Create"*
3. Give your test environment a name, such as *"mytest"*
4. Decide which version of Python or R it should be based on.
5. Click on the *"Create"* button at the bottom right of the dialog box

When the environment creation is complete, select the environment and install the package you're having trouble with:

[image: Add package to new environment]

1. Select *"Environments"*
2. Select *"mytest"*, the environment you just created
3. Select *"All"* for the search scope
4. Search for *"Spyder"*
5. Click the box beside the package name to select it for installation
6. Click on the *"Apply"* button at the bottom right
7. Try again!

If it now works then you've established that the problem is with some mix-up in the main environment you're using.  To resolve that you'll need to refer to the command line "force update" strategy described below.

Alternatively you can create a fresh environment using the strategy above, but include in it the *"anaconda"* package so you'll have a full featured set of tools.

### Try from the command line

Sometimes you get more details regarding what's going wrong if you run the program from the command line.  You can get to the command line as follows:

[image: Navigator open terminal]

1. Select *"Environments"*
2. Select the environment you are trying to use (if in doubt, use `root` or `base`, which are the defaults)
3. Select the triangle/arrow
4. Select "Open Terminal"

Now from the command line you should try doing:

`conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update spyder`

This will update the *Spyder* package (execute `conda update jupyter` if you want to update Jupyter Notebook)

Now try to run Spyder by executing this command:

`spyder`

If it doesn't work you should have more useful information as to the cause of the problem (the command for Jupyter Notebook is `jupyter notebook`, with a space between the two parts).

### But even Navigator isn't working

If you can't successfully start Navigator then you should get to the command line (*Terminal.app* in macOS, *Start->cmd.exe* on Windows), then navigate to where Anaconda is installed (often in `/Anaconda`, `$HOME/Anaconda` or `/opt/anaconda`) and from there go to the `Scripts` directory (Windows) or the `bin` directory (macOS, Linux).  Now execute the three `conda` commands above (for macOS and Linux users you may need to use `./conda` instead of just `conda`).  Once you've done that, try launching Anaconda Navigator with the command `anaconda-navigator`.

### Force a package reinstall

Sometimes the software package, even if it is up to date, can be corrupted.  This can happen if you've blended `pip install spyder` or similar commands that have changed the conda package software.  To try and fix that you can do a force re-install as follows:

```
conda install --force spyder
```

If it appears there are problems with any of the dependencies then you can try and force install those.  For the exact issue listed above, this would be the fix (Qt5 has been corrupted):

```
conda install --force qt
```

### What to do if you're still stuck

If at this point you're still stuck you've hopefully got enough information to share with people who can help you: StackOverflow (tagging with one or more of `#Anaconda` `#Spyder` `#Jupyter`), the [Anaconda issue tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/new) or one of the Anaconda support options [listed here](https://www.anaconda.com/support/).

When asking for further help it is advisable to include:

- What you wanted to happen
- What actually happened
- The exact command you executed
- The output you received
- Status of Anaconda as output by `conda info -a`

Screenshots are great for GUI-based operations, cut-and-paste for anything textual.